# Fedora 31 поворот экрана

Tags: fedora, display

Помогите. Как мне перевернуть изображён на экране? Поставил на планшет (irbis tw48) fedora 31.

Comment: Явно не по теме (этот вопрос никак не связан с темой Stack Overflow на русском)

Comment: А мне посоветовали сюда. Говорили, что здесь помогли решить эту проблему